# Swiss Franc Symbol

Tags: symbols

I am looking for the currency symbol for Swiss Franc? Similar to the euro symbol for the European currency.

```
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
...
\EUR{13,95}
```

Comment: There is no dedicated symbols for Swiss francs.  You simply typeset these as `100 Fr.` or more international as `100 CHF`.

Comment: For smaller fractions you might want to use `Rp.` for Rappen.

Answer (score 5):

Even though Swiss francs are not an SI unit, the `siunitx` package is really convenient to typeset numbers with units.  You simply declare CHF a new unit with

```
\DeclareSIUnit\CHF{CHF}
```

If you now want to change the representation from CHF to, say, Fr. throughout the whole document, all you have to do is adjust the definition to

```
\DeclareSIUnit\CHF{Fr.}
```

Here a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\CHF{CHF}
%\DeclareSIUnit\CHF{Fr.}
\begin{document}
\SI{100}{\CHF}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the symbol for the Swiss Franc just CHF? you could just build something like `\newcommand{\CHF}[1]{#1\,\textrm{CHF}}` or something along these lines.

**EDIT:**
changed `{\rm...}` to `\textrm{...}`, thanks!

Comment: Don't use `{\rm ...}`! Use `\textrm{...}` instead.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, thats my quick& dirty text-in-math style...

Comment: @audiophiel don't use `\rm` in math either:-)